# Javascript won't trigger on mobile - but works fine on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

)

So..I got this kind of a weird problem. First of all, I know there is some difference between mobile and desktop, but none seems to work.
I think it's something with my bootstrap, because if I remove my bootstrap then it would work - So in this case I don't think it's the "click.funktion".

My code is as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Danish Bread Studio</title>
    <!-- Almindelig CSS -->
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dbs, .raavarer, .baeredygtighed, .butikker").hide();
        $("#topleft, #topright, #bottomleft, #bottomright").click(function(){
                $(".dbs, .raavarer, .baeredygtighed, .butikker").hide();
                return false;
        });
        $("#topleft").click(function(){
                $(".dbs").show();
                return false;
        });
        $("#topright").click(function(){
                $(".raavarer").show();
                return false;
        });
        $("#bottomleft").click(function(){
                $(".baeredygtighed").show();
                return false;
        });
        $("#bottomright").click(function(){
                $(".butikker").show();
                return false;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Generelt -->
<nav class="hidden-xs">
    <div>
        <li><a id="topleft" class="topleft" href="#">DANISH<br>BREAD<br>STUDIO<br></a></li>
        <li><a id="topright" class="topright" href="#">RÅVARER</a></li>
        <li><a id="bottomleft" class="bottomleft" href="#">BÆRE-<br>DYGTIGHED</a></li>
        <li><a id="bottomright" class="bottomright" href="#">BUTIKKER</a></li>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Mobil -->
<nav class="visible-xs navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Danish Bread Studio</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a id="topleft" href="#">DANISH BREAD STUDIO</a></li>
        <li><a id="topright" href="#">RÅVARER</a></li>
        <li><a id="bottomleft" href="#">BÆREDYGTIGHED</a></li>
        <li><a id="bottomright" href="#">BUTIKKER</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="box" class="dbs">
  Lorem putent definiebas mea ex, ne pro probo graeci. Ei eam insolens perpetua tractatos, et nam ponderum evertitur, ius omnes mnesarchum comprehensam no. Offendit postulant ex mel, cum adolescens scripserit ne, te sumo tacimates splendide est. No natum simul nemore mea, prima graeco elaboraret sed cu, mea labores antiopam te.1
</div>
<div id="box" class="raavarer">
  Lorem putent definiebas mea ex, ne pro probo graeci. Ei eam insolens perpetua tractatos, et nam ponderum evertitur, ius omnes mnesarchum comprehensam no. Offendit postulant ex mel, cum adolescens scripserit ne, te sumo tacimates splendide est. No natum simul nemore mea, prima graeco elaboraret sed cu, mea labores antiopam te.2
</div>
<div id="box" class="baeredygtighed">
  Lorem putent definiebas mea ex, ne pro probo graeci. Ei eam insolens perpetua tractatos, et nam ponderum evertitur, ius omnes mnesarchum comprehensam no. Offendit postulant ex mel, cum adolescens scripserit ne, te sumo tacimates splendide est. No natum simul nemore mea, prima graeco elaboraret sed cu, mea labores antiopam te.3
</div>
<div id="box" class="butikker">
  Lorem putent definiebas mea ex, ne pro probo graeci. Ei eam insolens perpetua tractatos, et nam ponderum evertitur, ius omnes mnesarchum comprehensam no. Offendit postulant ex mel, cum adolescens scripserit ne, te sumo tacimates splendide est. No natum simul nemore mea, prima graeco elaboraret sed cu, mea labores antiopam te.4
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dude, Always put your script code before closing body tag. Its best practice

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. My script code is in the head. I would say that is before the body tag :P Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you put your script before </body> tag , that i ment

Comment: `id` attribute must be unique. You have several elements with `id="box"`.

Comment: Okay. I think I got that, but why can't their be several id's? Like the "class". Is this just a "rule"?

Comment: @PankajLadhar @KamK script before closing body is _just_ a best practice to speed up document processing. But since you're using `$(document).ready(...)` this is certainly not an error. And yes, `id` **must** be unique. How would you identify things, if everything has the same name? ;)

Comment: #KamK: One may have multiple id. I mean, it is not like your browser crashes or your computer explodes if you use them, yet it is called bad practise since id is short for identifier (=unique) and also it has some sideeffects on selectors like getElementById() or $('#'). You could select them similair to classes with querySelectorAll() tho.

Comment: Haha! Okay. I see.
Well, I use the same ID because I want the same styling (for the "box"). And for my 2 menu I use the ID's because I want the same thing to happen.

Specially the ID's at the menu would be a problem for me to change, because I would have to write two different JavaScripts.

Comment: Not really, you can select all classes the same.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But would it solve anything to rename it all?

Comment: Hey again :-)

I solved this by renaming my id's for the second menu (mobile) and then added them to my Javascript :-)

Thank for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Put your script code and bottom.

Try this :- 
​$(document).on('click', '#bottomright', function(event) {
   $(".butikker").show();
   return false;        
});
```

Comment: If I does this, all my "box" will be showing up at loading the website - and none functions will works. It's like its overruling the "$(document).ready(function()". This is right, yes?